# sed replace exact match of the word

Tags: regex, replace, sed, match, cpu-word

I a situation, where i have to replace exact same word in a string. For example :

String: `Dog DogCat CatDog Dog Cat Cdog ratdog Dog dog`

I tried following cmd, but it is not working, i use AIX:

```
echo "Dog DogCat CatDog Dog Cat Cdog ratdog Dog dog " | sed  -i 's/"\<Dog\>"/[[:blank:]]/'
```

expected Output:  `DogCat CatDog Cat ratdog`

Please help me out.

-Hanmant

Comment: Where is "Cdog" gone?

Comment: try to remove double quotes and use a literal space as replacement. use the modifiers g (for a global research) and i (for a caseless research) (put them after the last slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `sed -i 'script' file` only works if you have GNU sed. Do you really have GNU sed installed on AIX? I doubt it. Also, `-i` makes no sense in this context anyway. You're modifying a stream coming from a pipe, not file.

Second, POSIX does not specify `\<` and `\>`, though I know at least GNU sed and Solaris sed accept them. BSD sed on the other hand, use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` to match the same.

If the `sed` on AIX accepts `\<` and `\>` to match start-of-word and end-of-word respectively, AND it is POSIX compliant, then this might do what you want:

```
echo "Dog DogCat CatDog Dog Cat Cdog ratdog Dog dog " | sed 's/\<[Dd]og\>//g'
```

I also don't understand why you put a regex construct like `[[:blank:]]` in the replacement part of the s command. The replacement part is not a regular expression.

For a POSIX compliant version:

```
echo ... | sed 's/ [Dd]og  */ /g; s/^[Dd]og  *//; s/ [Dd]og$//'
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you know http://regex101.com/ ? There you can test your regex strings directly... Try replacing [blank] with /[[:space:]]+/

Comment: WOW....that's worked for me and thanks for the site referance i will dig through it. i know i little weak with regex.